# Windows Explorer: Create File Shortcut and Select it

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, windows-10

In Windows 7, when you created a file/folder shortcut in the Windows Explorer, then the shortcut was automatically selected which made it easy to cut/copy that shortcut somewhere else.

But in Windows 8/10, when you create a file/folder shortcut, the shortcut is not selected.

Is there any configuration to make Windows 8/10 to select the created shortcut?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I just tried and the new folder is automatically selected in Windows 10 ...

Comment: My question was  probably not clear.  I'm not talking about new folder.  I'm talking about creating a shortcut of an existing file or folder. I've seen others having the same problem in Windows 8/10; so, it's not just me.